# ajax image upload and preview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax

i have created a webform.in that there is file upload.

i want to upload the image and show the thumbnail image on fileupload select,and On page submit i want to save the image path to database.

how can u implement it using ajax.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking there is no way to implement an actual ajax file upload as its not supported by browsers. Html 5 has a lot more stuff you can do with file uploads.

You can implement your own hack using iframes, I have done this before. Basically you have an iframe that just has a form with the fileupload control on it and auto submit the form then call out to the parent window to update it when complete.

Alternatively use a pre built control something like the telerik one, you should be able to find a free one. http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/upload.aspx.